# How to deal with responses from an API which may contain an Array or Dictionary?

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I have an API call which checks for the UserLogin and Password and sends a response based on whether the username and password Pairs are correct or not.

The API returns a dictionary if the username-password pair is incorrect and an array of dictionaries if the username-password is correct.

The problem I face is that I am unable to downcast the response from Alamofire to a particular data type.

```
   func afLoginDriver(firstName: String,password:String,completion: @escaping ([Dictionary<String, Any>])->Void){
    let driverLoginURL = "URL here.."
    let parameters = ["firstName" : firstName, "Password" : password]
    AF.request(driverLoginURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let driverLoginResponse = response.value as? [Dictionary<String, Any>]
                completion(driverLoginResponse)
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The variable driverLoginResponse throws up an error if the username-password pairs is incorrect as it is only a dictionary and not an array of dictionary.

I tried using the guard let statement but still was not able to get this to work.

Comment: Hey, check out my method, it is different and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Codable` and `enum` for that but consider this:

First, implement an `enum` with any possible response:

```
enum LoginDriverResponseValue {
    case dictionary([String: Any])
    case array([[String: Any]])
    case string(String)
    case unknown(Any)
}
```

then, change the function signature to adapt with that enum:

```
func afLoginDriver(firstName: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (LoginDriverResponseValue)->Void) {
,,,
}
```

And lastly, switch on the enum and call corresponding completion:

```
guard let responseValue = response.value else { return }

switch responseValue {
case let result as [String: Any]: completion(.dictionary(result))
case let result as [[String: Any]]: completion(.array(result))
case let result as String: completion(.string(result))
default: completion(.unknown(responseValue))
}
```

### - More encapsulated way:

you can encapsulate `responseValue` type detection into the `enum LoginDriverResponseValue`:

```
extension LoginDriverResponseValue {
    init(responseValue: Any) {
        switch responseValue {
        case let result as [String: Any]: self = .dictionary(result)
        case let result as [[String: Any]]: self = .array(result)
        case let result as String: self = .string(result)
        default: self = .unknown(responseValue)
        }
    }
}
```

So then the only thing you need in the function will be:

```
guard let responseValue = response.value else { return }
completion(LoginDriverResponseValue(responseValue: responseValue))
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Cast the response values to the potential Types, and handle each:

```
if let responseOne = response.value as? [String: Any] {
    // ...
} else if let responseTwo = response.value as? [[String: Any]] {
    // ...
}
```

2. You could use Codable:

```
struct Response: Codable {
   var valueOne: [String: Any]?
   var valueTwo: [[String: Any]]?
}
```